# USB 3G Dongle Market

Tags: usb, wireless

What is the best USB 3G dongle on the market right now to use with my Macbook Pro running MacOS? I am looking for something under $50 that rivals WIFI and Ethernet type of speed. I am looking for the best bps for the best price. I understand 3G is not going to be as fast as WIFI or Ethernet.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Hardware Recs! Unfortunately, your question in it's current form is a bit too broad. We can make a better personalized recommendation if you clearly outline your budget, needs and expectations for a USB 3G dongle recommendation.

Comment: I have edited out the off-topic questions, as they are more suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Can you add your target speed, as WiFi and Ethernet are way too broad. (Google Fiber has Ethernet speeds up to 1000 Mbps. 3G only goes up to about 21.6 Mbps).